# SQL Server on Azure: "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm running a script locally in Powershell that loops bcp, copying hundreds of excel files to a database on Azure (I simply entered the network information as arguments to bcp). On each execution of the loop, I also make a query that updates a column of the table. At the beginning, it works fine. But about a minute in, it slows to a halt and finally produces this error.

```
47680 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 18250  Average : (2612.60 rows per sec.)
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Execution Timeout 
Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
```

I'm not sure what's going on here. Here's the query it's timing out on:

```
$query = "UPDATE $tableName SET jobID = $dir_id where jobID is NULL;"
$sqlCmd3 = $connection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCmd3.Connection = $connection
$sqlCmd3.CommandText = $query
$sqlCmd3.ExecuteReader() *>$null
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use "**ExecuteNonQuery**" instead of your "**ExecuteReader**"?
Execute reader opens a stream to read from which you should close by calling "**EndExecuteReader** ". Also, you use update statement which is NonQuery statement - just use ExecuteNonQuery instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix it :(. Same exact error.

Comment: Have you checked how long does it take to execute this in managment studio?
You might want increase query timeout. From ms docks:
"-t query_timeout
Specifies the number of seconds before a command (or SQL statement) times out. This option sets the sqlcmd scripting variable SQLCMDSTATTIMEOUT. If a time_out value is not specified, the command does not time out. The querytime_out must be a number between 1 and 65534. If the value supplied is not numeric or does not fall into that range, sqlcmd generates an error message."

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Jakob is the correct answer. It is not enough to set timeout on your sql server connection as the sql command it self also has a timeout. Increase both if you have timeout issues.